# How can I change the CommonsWare cwac thumbnailAdapter to cache to the SD Card?

Tags: android, listview, caching, thumbnails, imageview

I am using Mark Murphy's ThumbnailAdapter in a project to cache and display images from the web in a list view.  It works well, except that it caches to internal memory.  I can't figure out how to modify it to cache to external memory.

Any advice?

cwac-thumbnail: http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-thumbnail

Comment: Well, he's on SO so I bet he will eventually answer you himself!

Comment: I was hoping for and counting on that ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `ThumbnailAdapter` is a nice interface, the caching and stuff underneath it is a big steaming pile of...rather unimpressive code. It's on my list of things to rewrite, someday.

That being said, you supply the root to the cache via the constructor to the `SimpleWebImageCache`, so you should be able to use a path on the SD card for that. You give the `SimpleWebImageCache` to the `ThumbnailAdapter` via the `ThumbnailAdapter` constructor.

Comment: Ah.  I see.  Any recommendations for a caching mechanism that is less steamy?  I was pretty happy with Fedor's ImageLoader from his LazyList demo, but I get OOM errors.

Comment: @jonfhancock: Off the top of my head, no. I haven't gone looking for a  caching solution in over a year. BTW, official support for these CWAC components is over at the `cw-android` Google Group: http://groups.google.com/group/cw-android I might miss a question here on SO just due to volume of traffic.

Comment: Oh great! I didn't know that was there.